# /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model service fails

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In ROS electric, I want to spawn models in gazebo in a programmatic way via the /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model service. So I wrote a node implementing an according client but when I try to load models I get the following error from Gazebo: 'SpawnModel: Failure - model format is not URDF (nor COLLADA).' This also happens when I try calling the service from a terminal, e.g., rosservice call /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model '{model_name: "coke_can", model_xml: "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects/coke_can.urdf", robot_namespace: "/foo", initial_pose: {position: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, orientation: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1}}, reference_frame: "world"}'. Trying to spawn the same object via rosrun gazebo spawn_model ... works perfectly fine. The error occurs in /gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp in the method 'bool IsURDF(std::string model_xml)'. The TiXmlDocument which is parsed there always seems to be empty. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28190//gazebo/spawn_urdf_model-service-fails/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to literally serialize the urdf file into a data structure. The service does not ask for the file path of the urdf, but rather the actual urdf. You might want to use the [urdf parser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file).

I'm not sure if this works in C++ or not, but in Python, I simply read the entire contents of a urdf file directly into a string variable, and that works just fine.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-02-23**:
Indeed, also in C++ reading the urdf file contents into a string and use this string in the SpawnModel service works. Thanks for your help!